# Miscallaneous Scripts Set in Config->General->Design not showing

Tags: magento-1.9

Bit of a strange one.

I have put a script in the miscellaneous scripts section in
**Configuration->General->Design**, but it is not showing when I look at the page source. I have tried putting `<script>code here</script>` and just plain text, such as 12345, but when I refresh the website, it does not show in the page source.

I have refreshed caches through Magento admin etc. but it still just does not update. Tried logging out and back in, same thing. The text I enter shows in the database, so it is getting saved back, but just not showing on frontend.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the theme did not include th logic for this.
Try using the out of the box themes, rwd/default or base/default.
I know that code works out of the box so I imagine it's a custom theme getting in the way.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was with caching in the end!

For some reason the clear cache functions in magento admin just were not working. I manually deleted everything under var/cache, as well as a cache folder for a full page cache extension I have installed, and the changes came through fine!

Thanks!